# Return array from PHP Function

Tags: php, arrays, function

I need a function to return an array as an associate or object, with one input. Here's the code.

```
function fetch_article($key) {
    global $sysconfig;
    if ($sysconfig['datastore'] == 'wincache') {
          $data = wincache_ucache_get($key);
          return $data;
    }elseif ($sysconfig['datastore'] == 'apc'){
          $data = apc_fetch($key);
          return $data;
    }elseif ($sysconfig['datastore'] == ''){
          $data = $db->query("SELECT * FROM pages_content WHERE id = '" . $key . "'");
              $data = $data->fetch_assoc();
              return $data;
    }
}
```

I don't have that much experience working with functions, so please do bear with me.

Comment: What's the problem? Put one more "}"at the end, and this code should work well.

Comment: @Scorpil, provide an answer and you might get it accepted.

Comment: Sorry about that, in the third case, where the result set is an array, so $data['name'] might be produced, doesn't come out. In 500s the script.

Comment: It seems that I was focussing on the wrong thing. $db was not globalised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's no problem to just return the variable holding the array object.